# Vue.js: Is it possible to do "Conditional compilation" with a Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vuejs2

In for example Swift/iOS development, it's possible to differentiate builds for different environments with "flags" such as:

```
#if STAGING
  // one set of logic here
#endif

#if PRODUCTION
  // another set of logic here
#endif
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with a Vue.js project, and how would we go about doing it? I am aware of makes different routes conditionally available for different roles (which is also quite neat), but I am optimally looking for the option to differentiate on a source code level.

Hope someone has some great insights! It could include:

- How to exclude parts of a file (such as the `#if STAGING` above) from a build target
- How to exclude entire files from a build target
- etc.

Comment: vue uses webpack - to add your needs add them to vue.config.js at root level when using vue-cli, no sure if there is a pragma plugin for webpack though ^^

Comment: There is also [this library](https://github.com/nippur72/ifdef-loader) that allows you to do it exactly the way you want it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the ability to use this syntax

```
 if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        console.log("this is the prod env!!!!!!!!!!");
        config.output.path = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
    }
```

make sure that when you run the script with the correct env's for each environment (local, dev, staging, prod etc ..) :D

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! We'll definitely try it out. But I am also hoping someone has another solution up their sleave, because quoting on of my colleagues when I asked them: "Well yeah, that might work, but it's definitely not pretty :-P"

Answer (score 0):

just change the vue-loader output.

the source code

```
    <template v-if="process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'">
      development only
    </template>
```

default output

```
var render = function() {
  var _vm = this
  var _h = _vm.$createElement
  var _c = _vm._self._c || _h
  return _c(
    "div",
    { attrs: { id: "app" } },
    [
      _vm.process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? [_vm._v(" development only ")]
        : _vm._e(),
      _c("router-view")
    ],
    2
  )
}
```

just use regex to replace _vm.process.env. by process.env is ok.

```js
// webpack.config.js
    module: {
      rules: [{
        // must set post
        enforce: 'post',
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: [{
          loader: './myLoader'
        }]
      }]
    }


// myLoader.js
module.exports = function (source, map) {
  if (source.indexOf('_vm.process.env') > -1) {
    source = source.replace(/_vm.process.env/g, 'process.env')
  }
  this.callback(
    null,
    source,
    map
  )
}
```

Final the vue-loader result change

```js
var render = function() {
  var _vm = this
  var _h = _vm.$createElement
  var _c = _vm._self._c || _h
  return _c(
    "div",
    { attrs: { id: "app" } },
    [
      // change to true
       true
        ? [_vm._v(" development only ")]
        : undefined,
      _c("router-view")
    ],
    2
  )
}
```